# Importing CSS with res.send(html)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a web app served from an express server.

The reverse proxy the app sits behind will request /error on an internal http error so I need to send some basic html to browser to alert this.

```
module.exports = (request, response) => {
  const { query: { status } } = request;

  response.send(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <base href="/">
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>It looks like something has gone wrong/h1>
          <h3>There was an error trying to access this portal.</h3>
          <h3>Error code: ${status}</h3>
          <p>${message}</p>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
};
```

The issue is I cannot import a stylesheet - and I'm not sure you can when you send html as a string like this?

The sheet 'styles.css' that sits in the same dir as this js file and isn't picked up from `__dirname + 'styles.css'` or plain `styles.css`.

Any pointers?

Comment: why don`t to create an html file, and create sendFile method?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich I thought it would be easier to send in a js file to include variables.

Comment: try to import to the js file `const style = require('./style.css')`